# deleting entries with JPA and subqueries

Tags: sql, jpa, criteria

I just wrote an sql query :

```
DELETE FROM basisgegevens.gm_persoonburgstaat pbs 
WHERE (pbs.ingangsdatum, pbs.id_persoon) in (
  SELECT pbs2.ingangsdatum, pbs2.id_persoon 
  FROM basisgegevens.gm_persoonburgstaat pbs2 
  WHERE pbs2.ingangsdatum = pbs.ingangsdatum 
  AND pbs2.id_persoon = :persoonID 
  AND pbs2.id_persoonburgerlijkestaat > pbs.id_persoonburgerlijkestaat);
```

I need to rewrite it to JPQL, but am getting stuck with the subquery refrencing the outer query.

```
public class PersoonBurgerlijkeStaatEntity {
@Column(name = "id_persoonburgerlijkestaat"
private Long identifier;
private Date ingangsdatum;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_persoon", referencedColumnName = "id_persoon", nullable = false)
private PersoonEntity persoon;
```

}

The persoon entity has an identifier

Can someone help me rewrite this?

Thanks

Comment: I assume basisgegevens is the schema and basisgegevens the table ?. And persoonburgstaat is the table for the entity PersoonBurgerlijkeStaatEntity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about this but give a try.

```
DELETE FROM persoonburgstaat person where (person.ingangsdatum, person identifier) in 
    (select p.ingangsdatum, p.identifier from persoonburgstaat p
        left join p.persoon per where per.id_persoon = :persoonID 
        AND per.id_persoonburgerlijkestaa > p.identifier)
```

the left join will make the outer query

But to be more sure post PersoonEntity entity as I think " id_persoonburgerlijkestaa " is the name of the column not the property and query will fail based on that.