# Best practices for massive deletion of rows in MySQL using JPA

Tags: mysql, performance, jpa, sql-delete

The title pretty much sums up what I am looking for here.

I am trying to delete >500000 rows from MySQL using either a Spring `JpaRepository#deleteInBatch(Iterable<T> batch)`, `CrudRepository#delete(Iterable<T> batch)` or a `JPADeleteClause` and either exhaustively creating >500000 delete statements.

```
entities.forEach(e->deleteClause.where(event.id.eq(e.getId())));
```

or creating batches via `in` clauses

```
Lists.partition(events, MAXIMUM_PACKET_SIZE).forEach(
        packet->deleteClause.where(event.id.in(packet.stream()
            .map(Event::getId)
            .collect(
                Collectors.toList())))
            .execute()
    );
```

Some of this methods fail due to thresholds in MySQL itself

> Memory capacity of N bytes for
>                      'range_optimizer_max_mem_size' exceeded. Range
>                      optimization was not done for this query.
>
> Packet for query is too large (4895385 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.

while the ones who eventually succeed are extremely time consuming.

Are there any best practices out there regarding these kind of scenarios?

I am mainly looking for an approach which is not going to affect any existing MySQL configuration. This is because I am looking for the least pervasive solutions at least as far as MySQL server configuration is concerned.

Comment: How many rows are you keeping

Comment: I'd say (~10, to potentially millions). Also because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410023/deleting-entries-with-jpa-and-subqueries) it is not that clear how to create a `select` subquery in a delete statement using `JPA` (using JPASubQuery). Thus the `entities` part in the code attached is created by a previous ran `select` query.

Comment: It might be worth posting in the dba forum

Comment: Several answers:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig